# XCode 6.1 - Missing Project templates (C++ Library and C++ STL Library)

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode6

All of sudden yesterday C++ library and STL C++ library templates disappeared from my XCode 6.1 installation. Here is how it is supposed to look like:
[image]

And here is how it looks like now:

[image]

I uninstalled XCode completely and re-installed it but still those templates were missing. Is anyone else experiencing the same problem? How to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Never mind! The user interface to select project templates has changed a little bit in XCode 6.1 . Here is how to create a C++ library project:

To create a C++ library, select Library template (Even thought the description says: 'This template builds library that links against the Cocoa framework'. It can be a little confusing but you can change it to make it a C++ library in next step).

[image]

Click Next, and then you can choose the Framework Type to be Plain C++ Library, Cocoa, or STL (C++ Library). You can also specify Type to be Static or Dynamic.

[image]

I feel like an idiot now. I wasted at least couple of hours reinstalling XCode and trying some other things. I hope it saves someone else's time.